# As administrator How can I get all data from a collection in Firestore regardless which user created them. I use Pinia and Vue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, pinia

I have storeAuth.js user collection and I created a users collection, the field of role is set to "admin". use email and password for authentication, I use actions to judge if the user role is "admin" or just a "user", If it is "admin" I  create and fetch the Transaction regardless user.id,   I use addDOC to create a collection named Transactions,  I use uerySnapshot.forEach((doc) to fetch Transactions, and in Firestore I do see two collections which are users and Transactions, they are independent to each other, there is no ownership in any Transaction document data.  My problem is that as role ="admin" I can only fetch Transactions that were created by a Logged in user but  not all Transaction regarless who created them. [image: Firestore Transaction collections]
[image: users collection]

Part of Vue code is as follwoing:

```
actions: {
// ----------Init------------------------
init() {
  const storeAuth = useStoreAuth();
  if (storeAuth.user.role === "admin") {
    // Admins can access all transactions
    transactionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Transactions");
  } else {
    // Regular users access their own transactions
    transactionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Transactions");
    transactionsCollectionQuery = query(
      transactionsCollectionRef,
      where("userId", "==", storeAuth.user.id),
      orderBy("date", "desc")
    );
    this.getTransactions();
  }
},

    //---------------Query  -------------------
    transactionsCollectionQuery = query(
      transactionsCollectionRef,
      orderBy("date", "desc")
    );
    this.getTransactions();
   }
 },

    //------ Create Transaction-------
    async addTransaction(
    custFirstName,
    custLastName,
    custAdd,
    custCity,
    //....// other info
    //----Form fields map to ----
     const transactData = {
        tranFirst: custFirstName,
        tranLast: custLastName,
        address: custAdd,
        city: custCity,
  //..........more fields....
  }
  await addDoc(transactionsCollectionRef, transactData);
    } else {
 //------------error handle-----

 //----Fetch Transaction as admin-------
 async getTransactions() {
  console.log("Fetching transactions...");
  this.transactionsLoaded = false;

  if (getTransactionsSnapshot) getTransactionsSnapshot(); // 
  unsubscribe from any active listener

  getTransactionsSnapshot = onSnapshot(
    transactionsCollectionQuery,
    (querySnapshot) => {
      let transactions = [];
      console.log(transactions);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let transaction = {
          id: doc.id,
          custFirstName: doc.data().tranFirst,
          custLastName: doc.data().tranLast,
          custAdd: doc.data().address,
          custCity: doc.data().city,
         //....more fields...
          };
        transactions.push(transaction);
      });
      this.transactions = transactions;
      this.transactionsLoaded = true;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("error.message: ", error.message);
       }
     );
   },
 //-------Firebase rule-----

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
// Allow users to read and write their own data
match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}

// Allow authenticated users to write to the Transactions collection
match /Transactions/{document=**} {
  allow read: if true; // Adjust this to your needs for reading 
  transactions
  allow write: if request.auth != null; // Allow authenticated users to 
 write
  }
 }
}
```

I have tried to figure out why users and Transactions coupled together for many days. Please help me solve this Administrator problem. If role = "admin" I need read all Transactions regardless who created them.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your firestore rules?

Comment: The Rule:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow users to read and write their own data
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    // Allow authenticated users to write to the Transactions collection
    match /Transactions/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true; // Adjust this to your needs for reading transactions
      allow write: if request.auth != null; // Allow authenticated users to write
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I modified my action block and  getTransactions() as following code and works well, admin can fetch all data of transaction and a logged in user can only ftech his own data.  You need to set role of your user collection document to "admin" or " user" .

```
 actions: {
// ----------Initi------------------------

init() {
  const storeAuth = useStoreAuth();
  console.log("storeAuth.user:", storeAuth.user);
  console.log(storeAuth.user.id);
  console.log(storeAuth.user.role);
  console.log("admin...check");
  if (storeAuth.user.role === "admin") {
    // Admins can access all transactions
    transactionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Transactions");
    console.log("admin...YES");
    console.log(storeAuth.user.id);
    // ------add query--------------
    transactionsCollectionQuery = query(
      transactionsCollectionRef,
      orderBy("date", "desc")
    );
    this.getTransactions();
  } else {
    console.log(storeAuth.user.role);
    console.log("admin...No !");
    // Regular users access their own transactions
    transactionsCollectionRef = collection(db, "Transactions");
    transactionsCollectionQuery = query(
      transactionsCollectionRef,
      where("userId", "==", storeAuth.user.id),
      orderBy("date", "desc")
    );
    this.getTransactions();
   }
 },
    enter code here
async getTransactions() {
  console.log("Fetching transactions...");
  console.log("Query for transactions:", transactionsCollectionQuery);
  this.transactionsLoaded = false;

  if (getTransactionsSnapshot) getTransactionsSnapshot(); // unsubscribe from any active listener

  getTransactionsSnapshot = onSnapshot(
    transactionsCollectionQuery,
    (querySnapshot) => {
      let transactions = [];
      console.log(transactions);
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let transaction = {
          id: doc.id,
          userId: doc.data().userId,
          custFirstName: doc.data().tranFirst,
          custLastName: doc.data().tranLast,
          custAdd: doc.data().address,
          custCity: doc.data().city,
          custState: doc.data().state,
          custZip: doc.data().zip,
          custPhone: doc.data().phone,
          custEmail: doc.data().email,
//-------------------other info---------
   };
        transactions.push(transaction);
      });
      this.transactions = transactions;
      this.transactionsLoaded = true;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("error.message: ", error.message);
    }
  );
},
```